# Why doesn't get() in ResultSet throw exception when 'getting' wrong type of data?

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

Say I have table `cities` with 2 columns. One is `ID` (**integer primary key**), other is `NAME` (**text not null**).
When I do something like:

```
resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select * from cities");
while (resultSet.next()){
System.out.println("ID and Name: " + resultSet.getInt(1) + "," + resultSet.getString(2));
}
```

I get nice result of:

```
ID and Name: 1,london
ID and Name: 2,madrid
ID and Name: 3,paris
```

But! Watch what happens when I change print statement to this. Notice how **get() methods** have incorrect data type from actual data in database.

```
System.out.println("ID and Name: " + resultSet.getString(1) + "," + resultSet.getInt(2));
```

What surprised me is that program didn't crash. Instead it got:

```
ID and Name: 1,0
ID and Name: 2,0
ID and Name: 3,0
```

Why is it designed this way? Shouldn't I get some sort of `castException`? And why this result? Also how it can convert primary key to String (when I didn't do any explicit casting)?

Comment: Because of JDBC 4.2 Specification, Table B.6, *Type Conversions Supported by `ResultSet` getter methods'.

Comment: In a properly behaving driver, the `resultSet.getInt(2)` should have resulted in an exception and not returned the value 0. Which database and driver are you using? In any case, your basic question is answered in the [javadoc of `ResultSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/ResultSet.html): _"For the getter methods, a JDBC driver attempts to convert the underlying data to the Java type specified in the getter method and returns a suitable Java value."_

Comment: Thanks guys. Yep, it didn't make sense that it puts 0 there. I am using `sqlite-jdbc-3.30.1`. Something wrong with it except that type conversion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As documented in the [`ResultSet` javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/ResultSet.html):

> For the getter methods, a JDBC driver attempts to convert the
> underlying data to the Java type specified in the getter method and
> returns a suitable Java value. The JDBC specification has a table
> showing the allowable mappings from SQL types to Java types that can
> be used by the `ResultSet` getter methods.

So, being able to perform a `getString(..)` on an integer column is perfectly acceptable, and the driver will do the conversion for you (eg using `String.valueOf(int)` or something similar).

The [JDBC 4.3 specification](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr221/index3.html), appendix B, contains tables of mappings that the JDBC specification expects drivers to support, but be aware that some drivers might support more conversions than listed (and - unfortunately - some do not support all conversions listed).

The use of `getInt(..)` on a string-type column (eg `VARCHAR`) is also allowed, but comes with more limitations: the value must be parseable to an `int`. The example you show seems to be from a non-compliant driver that converts non-parseable values to `0` instead of throwing an exception.

On this, the JDBC 1.20 specification says:

> If you attempt an illegal conversion, or if a data conversion fails
> (for example if you did a getInt on a SQL VARCHAR value of “foo”),
> then a SQLException will be raised.

Although this is no longer explicitly mentioned in recent JDBC specifications, it is still expected behaviour. You should report a bug to the maintainer of your JDBC driver on this.

Answer (score -1):

The JDBC specification has a table which shows which all mapping of SQL types to Java types  that are allowed in ResultSet getter method.

Mostly getString() method is used to get SQL types CHAR and VARCHAR but it can be used to fetch any SQL type but it also has its limitation.
If you used it to retrieve a numeric type, then getString() converts numeric value to java String object, and in order to use that value it has to be converted back to numeric type before it can be operated as numeric type.

Comment: `getString()` cannot be used on CLOB, BLOB, ARRAY, REF, STRUCT, JAVA_OBJECT, ROW_ID,NCLOB, or SQLXML, according to the table you are referring to.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne The table specifies the minimum requirements; drivers are allowed to be more lenient.

Comment: This answer states specifically that 'getString can be used to fetch any SQL type`, and specificaly cites the table, which it is therefore misrepresenting.